# Reputation not rewarded

Tags: support, reputation

> [image]

Why was I not rewarded with the reputation for the 3 upvotes?

Answer (score 5):

It wasn't awarded because you hit the reputation cap today.

> https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/39240/yb609?tab=reputation

[image]

You have 330 points today. Even when you take away the association bonus that still leaves 230 points.

The limit is 200 points from votes plus any amount for accepts, bounties and association bonuses.

For more information see this FAQ question:

> [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: That means I lost those 30 points? I won't be getting it back?

Comment: @Yb609 - no, you haven't lost those points, you never had them in the first place. Read the linked question on how reputation works.